# $G$ a connected topological group, U open, then $\mathcal{U} = \cup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\; U^i$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ a connected topological group, and $U$ an open subset of $G$ that contains the identity element of $G$.  I want to solve the following problem:

> If $U^n$ is the set of the products $u_1 u_2 ...u_n$, with $u_i$ in $U$, show that $\mathcal{U} = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\; U^i$ is an open subgroup of $G$, and hence $\mathcal{U}=G$ .

The only part that is giving me problem is to prove that $\mathcal{U}$ is a subgroup. A hint given to the problem is to consider first an open set $V$, such that if $g$ in $V$ then $g^{-1}$ is in $V$. Obviously with $V$ in place of $U$, the property of subgroup is of direct comprobation. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose an open set $V\subseteq U$ containing the identity such that if $g\in V$ then $g^{-1}\in V$ (for instance, $V=U\cap U^{-1}$).  As you say, you can then easily show that $\mathcal{V}=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} V^i$ is an open subgroup of $G$.  Thus $\mathcal{V}=G$.  But $\mathcal{V}\subseteq\mathcal{U}$ since $V\subseteq U$, and so you must also have $\mathcal{U}=G$.

(Note that without the assumption that $G$ is connected, it is not necessarily true that $\mathcal{U}$ is a subgroup.  For instance, take $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $U=\{0,1\}$.)

Comment: Thanks. I understood the argument, but what guarantees that such an $V\subseteq U$ exist? I don't have much experience with topological groups, but what if $V=U\cap U^{-1} = \{e\}$?

Comment: Well, try proving that $U\cap U^{-1}$ has the properties you want.  Which ones do you have trouble proving?

Comment: Yes, $U\cap U^{-1}$ has the properties I need for the problem, but I don't see why $U\cap U^{-1} = \{e\}$ is not a possibility. Because in that case $\mathcal{V} = \{e\}$. Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that possibility.  The argument still shows that $\mathcal{V}=G$, so in that case you just conclude that $G$ is trivial.

Comment: You are right, the argument still works. Thank you.